# Wordpress Z-index issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, effect, box-shadow

This is the effect i want [CSS effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAJ4d.png)

I have tried this in a page of my wordpress theme but not working. Here is the case: 
when i untick the z-index the rotated box bar with shadow comes to the front side of the area but when i turn it back on the shadow just vanishes and the rotated bar is gone. The scenario behind this effect is hiding the rotated bar behind the background area while showing the shadow only. any solution for this please ?
Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box effect1">
<h3>Effect 1</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
     .box h3
      {
       text-align:center;
       position:relative;
       top:80px;
      }

     .box 
      {
       width:70%;
       height:200px;
       background:#FFF;
       margin:40px auto;
      }

     .effect2
      {
       position: relative;
      }

     .effect2:before, .effect2:after
      {
       z-index: -1;
       position: absolute;
       content: "";
       bottom: 15px;
       left: 10px;
       width: 50%;
       top: 80%;
       max-width:300px;
       background: #777;
       box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
       transform: rotate(-3deg);
      }

     .effect2:after
      {
       transform: rotate(3deg);
       right: 10px;
       left: auto;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS refers to "effect2" but your DIV has a class of "effect1"

When I change the DIV to "effect2" I see the styling you want.

Comment: sorry thats a mistake here. i already tried with the effect2. but the shadow doesnt show up there :(

Comment: Shows up here... https://jsfiddle.net/hssgqrd5/ You probably have other CSS settings on the page that interfere with the effect.